# How to handle a keypress Enter with Dart Web UI?

Tags: dart

I'd like to declaratively listen for an ENTER key press in an input field, with Dart's Web UI? I only want to run a method if ENTER was pressed, and I don't care about any other key.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Summary**

Dart's Web UI package can declaratively register handlers for various events, like click and keyUp. The keyUp event will fire for every single keyboard up event. To filter those events, and to listen to only specific keys, you need to look at the keyCode attribute. Luckily, Dart has a convenience class for normalizing keycodes across browsers. You can use all of this inside your declarative bind attributes. Read on to learn how!

**Listening for key presses**

The `InputElement` class has a stream of events for the keyUp event, called `onKeyUp` ([docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElementBase.html#onKeyUp)). The `onKeyUp` stream emits `KeyboardEvent` ([doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/KeyboardEvent.html)) instances.

```dart
final Stream<KeyboardEvent> onKeyUp;
```

**Old 'n Busted**

The `KeyboardEvent` provides a `keyCode` accessor that returns a system specific key code. Unfortunately, some systems have different key codes for the same semantic key. Luckily, Dart has a fix!

**New Hotness**

Use the `KeyEvent.wrap(KeyboardEvent parent)` ([doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/KeyEvent.html)) to emulating `KeyEvent` and normalizing confusing key codes!

```dart
new KeyEvent.wrap(keyboardEvent)
```

Now that you have an instance of `KeyEvent`, you can query its `keyCode` for a rational look into what key was pressed. The `keyCode` getter returns an `int`, but you can compare that against a list of keys from the `KeyCode` ([doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/KeyCode.html)) class.

```dart
var keyEvent = new KeyEvent.wrap(keyboardEvent);
if (keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
  // enter was pressed
}
```

**Cross-browser key presses FTW**

The `KeyEvent` and `KeyCode` classes help to normalize key codes across systems and browsers, so you don't need to worry about various incompatibilities.

**With Web UI**

Web UI lets you declaratively register event handling. You can listen for key events and check if the enter key was pressed. Here is an example:

```html
<input type="text" id="new-todo" on-key-up="if (new KeyEvent($event).keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) createNewTodo()">
```

Notice how `on-key-up` registers the if statement, which uses `KeyEvent` and `KeyCode` to normalize the key codes. The `createNewTodo` method is only called when the enter key was pressed.

Ta da!

Comment: This is extremely useful pattern.

Comment: I'd love to say on-key-enter. So I opened: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/357

Comment: Great answer, I just wanted to add that if you have a situation where you have one or more input fields and a submit button then you can also listen to the 'submit' event of the form. This way you don't need to explicitly listen for enter keypresses and button clicks and it covers all other edge-cases like submitting the form by pressing 'space' while focus is on the submit button etc :)

Comment: How do I tell what keyboardEvent needs to be?

`Exception: No top-level getter 'get:keyboardEvent' declared.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get:keyboardEvent'
Receiver: top-level
Arguments: [...]`

Comment: If you want something like CTRL+L are you supposed to add the constants? `if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.CTRL + KeyCode.L)...`. Doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Not Web UI, but this is another way to listen for and use keyboard input.

1) Listen for the key press:

```dart
void main() {
  ...    
  input.onKeyPress.listen(handleKeyEvent);    
  ...
}
```

2) Convert the resulting KeyboardEvent to a KeyEvent using the **KeyEvent.wrap(keyboardEvent)** constructor. Then, you can do as above by comparing your KeyEvent.keyCode with KeyCode.Enter:

```dart
void handleKeyEvent(KeyboardEvent event) {
  KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent.wrap(event);
  if (keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    handleInput();       
  }   
}
```

Comment: With Dart VM version: 1.13.2,  KeyboardEvent has a keyCode getter now. No more wrapping necessary.